# use Phantom 2 for real time image processing

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, raspberry-pi, phantom-types

I have a project to detect ripeness of specific fruit, I will use phantom 2 with autopilot feature to fly  through fruit trees and capture images then I want to make real time image processing.

I was searching a lot but didn't find the answers for the following questions.

can I use phantom 2 for real time image processing? can I connect 
raspberry pi to the phantom? and what I need? can I use python 2.7 +
opencv lib to write image processing codes?

Comment: if you don't specify what you want to process it is impossible to tell you if it can be processed in real time. do you have a working solution for that fruit ripeness detection which you just have to make fly somehow?

Answer (score 2):

I would be surprised if a off-the-shelf multicopter would comprise enough processing power to do any reasonable image processing on-board. It wouldn't make sense for the manufacturer.

But I guess it has some video or streaming capabilties or can be equipped with such. Then you can process the data on a remote computer, given that you are in transmission range.

If you have to process on a remote device it doesn't make any sense to request real-time processing. What for? I mean the multicopter can't do anything useful with real-time results and just for mapping or inspection purposes delay doesn't matter.

In general your question cannot be answered as no one can tell you if any hardware is capable of real-time processing without knowing how much there is to process.

To answer the rest of your questions:
You can connect a raspberry pi to the Phantom.
You can use pyhton 2.7 and opencv to write image processing code.

That you ask things like that makes me think that you might not be up to the job. So unless you have a team of talented people I guess it will take you years to come out with a usable and robust solution.